# Can not retrieve xampp jsxc message history

Tags: javascript, xampp, chat, openfire, instant-messaging

We are using jsxc javascript client to access openfire chat server. However we have problems loading the chat history. 
The history is stored in the database, we just do not know, how to retrieve it.

```
var url = 'servername';
var domain = 'https://' + url + ':7443/http-bind/';
var sid = jsxc.storage.getItem('sid');
if (sid == null) sid = username;

jsxc.init({
    xmpp: {
        url: 'https://' + url + ':7443/http-bind/',
        sid: sid
    },
    root: '/jsxc'
});

var jid = username + '@' + url;
jsxc.start(jid , password);
```

This is our initialization script. Do we have to add something else?
Best,
Bojan